# Display axis lines/border over graphics on plot

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, plot

I have a plot that doesn't appear to display its axis lines/border, despite this being the default setting. It's possible this is because the border is covered by the inserted graphics. How do I get the border to show up? Is there a way to get the axes to display above the graphics?

An MWE showing the issue is below. Any test image can be used, although the issue is most clear if the test image has a white background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=9.5cm,height=19.73344cm,
scale only axis=true,enlargelimits=false,
xtick pos=left,ytick pos=left,tick align=outside,scaled ticks=false]
\addplot graphics[xmin=5,xmax=10,ymin=5,ymax=10, includegraphics={trim=0px 0px 0px 14.97141px, clip, keepaspectratio}] {Images/test};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I am referring to the axis lines that surround a plot area, not a frame around the entire image area. If you compile my code the issue should be apparent.

Comment: I don't wish to add white space between the axis and the image as my usual images are mostly black and this will give them an obvious white border, which is undesirable. There's also the issue of adjusting the axis values to account for the extra space, which is not trivial.

Comment: I think you are searching for `axis on top` which should be added to the `axis` options, right?

Comment: You are welcome. Shall I write an answer or shall we close this question as being solved in the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358192/display-axis-lines-border-over-graphics-on-plot#comment882351_358192) you just need to add `axis in top` to the `axis` options to achieve the desired result.

Here with two screenshots showing the zoomed result of the following code, one time with `axis on top=false` and one time with `axis on top=true`. To better show the difference of the results I have drawn the axis lines in green.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=9.5cm,
        height=19.73344cm,
        scale only axis=true,
        enlargelimits=false,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left,
        tick align=outside,
        scaled ticks=false,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Draw axis lines, ticks, tick labels and grid lines on top of the plot
        % graphics.
        axis on top,
        % (for debugging purposes only, draw rhe axis lines in green)
        axis line style={
            green,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        % (replaced the image with a "test image" that is available on every
        %  system)
        \addplot graphics [
            xmin=5,xmax=10,ymin=5,ymax=10,
            includegraphics={
                trim=0px 0px 0px 14.97141px,
                clip,
                keepaspectratio,
            },
        ] {example-image};
%        ] {Images/test};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the zoomed result of above code]